# How do I assign different handler to one event listener like the click addEventListener. This is what I have being doing

Tags: javascript, handler, addeventlistener

```
Var a = document.querySelectorAll("img")
For(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    Var b = a[i].addEventListener ("click", tee, bee);

    Function tee () {
        Console.log("Hello")
    }

    Function bee () {
        Console.log("world")
    }
```

Comment: You can bind one function, which will then call `tee` and `bee`. E.g: `addEventListener("click", () => {tee(); bee();})`, you can pass through the event object if needed

Answer (score 0):

First of all case matters in JavaScript. `addEventListener` accepts single listener.

You can call the second function inside the function:

```js
var a=document.querySelectorAll("img") 
for(i=0; i<a.length; i++){
  var b = a[i].addEventListener("click", tee);
}
function tee (){
  console.log("Hello")
  bee();
}

function bee (){
  console.log("world")
}
```

```html
<img alt="111"/>
<img alt="222"/>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, I appreciate